# Can large earthquakes happen few times at same place(in days)

Tags: seismology, earthquakes, seismic

I want to know if large earthquakes can happen twice in the same place? I live in Istanbul/Turkey. In Canakkale/Turkey too many earthquakes happen for days! I know it is normal for this region but 4.8 , 4.9 , 5.0 , 5.3 etc. is this a normal thing? I'm not saying "months", every day atleast one earthquake...(In Richter Scale)

Is this OK? or not?

Comment: Are you asking whether such tremors are a sign of a bigger earthquake to come?

Comment: I'm not sure by what do you mean by "Is this OK"?.

Comment: That phrase is what suggests to me that he's really asking whether it foretells a major earthquake.

Comment: you should formulate your question more specifically, such that one can use the past global/regional seismicity to give you an answer in terms of "how often did this happen before"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and they are quite common, they are called [aftershocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aftershock).

An earthquake redistributes the stress that creates the quake across the fault line, which then creates new points of stress, which result in additional earthquakes, which further redistribute the stress again, and so on and so forth until all the energy is spent.

[Earthquake swarms](http://www.scsn.org/index.php/earthquakes/earthquake-swarms/) also exist.  They basically work on the same principle as aftershocks but are much stronger. They tend to occur in places where you have many faults in the same region.  The release of pressure on one fault causes movement that puts more stress on other faults, causing a cascade of quakes. California and other transform faults are famous for them. Here is rather nice BBC film about them.  http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2262rz_bbc-horizon-2003-earthquake-storms_shortfilms.